# Process or thread which is best ,faster and take less memory?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have 20 text files stored in hard disk each contains millions of information's about an educational organization.Suppose i have a method which will iterate text files in a loop and process .Which is best way to do the work  starting each thread for each text file(Factory.startnew()) or each process for each textfile(process.start())

**EDIT**
I have 8GB RAM ,8core server ,so thought of to process them in thread or process.Currently i am using process and i don't find any bottleneck as of now.But i am in dilemma for using threads or process

Comment: Use async await my friend , it will serve u good.

Comment: Threads are good for cpu intensive work , task are good for io/network related stuff

Comment: @loneshark99 Please elaborate. I am interested to hear your thoughts on that.

Comment: Please see this video and series -- very informative https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-2-Distinguish-CPU-Bound-work-from-IO-bound-work

Comment: Much can be gleaned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-19.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The reading speed of the harddisk will most likely be the bottleneck here.

So, depending on the processing you need to do on the data, it might or might not be interesting to use multiple threads (and I would certainly not use processes).

The most important thing however, will be to make sure that **no multiple threads are accessing the same physical disk at the same time**, because that would lead to a slowdown because of constantly switching and seeking of the hdd-heads.

I have done some testing with that recently, and in some cases (depending on the hdd and/or pc) the OS takes care of it and it doesn't make a big difference, but on another combination however, a slowdown could be seen to 1/10 of the normal speed.

So, if using multiple threads (only needed if the processing of your data takes longer than the reading from your hdd!), make sure you have a lock somewhere to prevent multiple threads reading from the disk at the same time.

You might also want to look into memory mapped files for this.

**edit**:

In case you are working with buffers, you could start one thread to continuously fill the buffers, while another thread processes the data.

**edit2** (in answer to Micky):

> "Process or thread which is best ,faster and take less memory?"

As I said, I would not use processes (due to the extra overhead). That leaves **threads, or no threads at all** - depending on the amount of processing that needs to be done on the data. If data is read directly from memory buffers (instead of using something like `readline` for example, where all bets would be off), one or max. two threads would probably be the best option (if the processing of the data is fast enough - testing and timing would be needed to be sure).

As for **speed and memory usage**: best option (for me) would be **memory mapped files** (with the files opened in forward only mode). This would not only take advantage of the efficiency of the OS disk cache, but would also access the kernel-memory directly - while, when working with (user)buffers, memory has to be copied from kernel- to userspace, which takes time and uses extra memory.

**IOCP**: ok, but depends on what the threads would be asking. For example, if 10 threads would be asking 100kB each time in turn (on the different files), 10 x 10ms seektime would be needed, while reading 100Kb would take less than 1ms. Seektimes for future requests would depend on how IOCP handles the caching, which would probably be the same as using memory-mapping, but I don't think IOCP would be any faster in this case.

And using IOCP, would probably also be copying/filling buffers in userspace (and probably harder to handle in general). But I have to say, while writing my answer I was thinking C/C++ (using direct access to memory buffers) only to see later that it was C#. Although the principles stay the same, maybe there's an easy way in C# to use async I/O with IOCP.

As for the speed-testing and avoiding the reading at the same time: I have done testing with more than 50 threads on large files (via memory mapping) - and if done correctly, no reading-speed is lost. On the other hand, when just firing some threads and letting them access the hdd at random (even in large blocks), total reading-speed could come down to 10% in some cases - and sometimes not at all. Same PC, other hdd, other results.

Comment: @Micky - thanks for your comments :) I added some text to the answer.

Comment: Marvellous. Thanks for update Danny +1